# The odds of two random elements of a group commuting and representation theory and notations

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

The [odds of two random elements of a group commuting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kIdb.png) is the number of conjugacy classes of the group

$$  \frac{ \{ (g,h): ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = 1 \} }{ |G|^2}  = \frac{c(G)}{|G|}$$

If this number exceeds 5/8, the group is Abelian.For example, see here.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91685/5-8-bound-in-group-theory
The following is another proof.

[image]

I have two question about this proof.

1.What does the notation $〈〉$($〈1〉,〈(dimρ)^2〉$) in the 6 line from the top mean?

2. If $x$ is ratio of representations with dimension at least 1, then ratio $1-x$ be representations with dimension $0$ or at least $2$. Why
   the author concludes $x・１＋(1-x)・４＜8/5$ ? I think our last goal is to
   prove $1$-dimensional representation occupies grater than $80$
   percent.Then commutative group should be trivial. Thus, $x$ should be
   percent of $1$-dimensional representation in all representations. What
   am I missing ?

Comment: You can get the proper font and formatting for operators like $\dim$ using `\dim`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

The angled brackets $\langle\rangle$ usually denote an average – the question is over what. The line you refer to is wrong; the right-hand equality has the same sum on both sides (the equation two lines further up says that $|G|$ is that sum, and cancelling it would imply $\langle(\dim\rho)^2\rangle=1$, which is what’s to be proved). Since the line is wrong, it’s hard to tell what it’s intended to average over. In the correct proof by Will Sawin that the paper cites from the MO post that you linked to, the averaging is done over all characters, i.e. over all irreducible representations $\rho$.

The first sentence in your second question is wrong – every representation has dimension at least $1$, so $x$ would be $1$; and even if there were $0$-dimensional representations, the complement of “at least $1$” would be “less than $1$”, not “$0$ or at least $2$”.

The argument in the proof is that if the average of an integer variable is $\le\frac85$, then, with $p_k$ representing the proportion of values $k$,

$$
\frac85\ge\sum_kp_kk\ge p_1+2(1-p_1)=2-p_1\;,
$$

and thus $p_1\ge\frac35$.